# Java image captcha solution like this one?

Tags: java, captcha, simplecaptcha

I tried different Java-related captcha solutions such as JCaptcha, SimpleCaptcha, etc. I am not satisfied. I could miss something.  What I really like is something very similar to this one in terms of generated characters and look and feel.

[image: http://drupal.org/node/468906]

Does anyone know of a Java solution generating an image VERY similar to the above one?

I also tried reCaptcha and don't like it. It often generates capcha code hard for people to type it right in the first try.

Comment: Well, people can also keep pressing the refresh button to generate a captcha on reCaptcha they actually like the look of ;)

Comment: @ChrisDennett  On the occasions when SO mistakes me for a bot, I will generally refresh the gaptcha once or twice before I can make head or tail of it.

Comment: that captcha you want is so weak that it might as well not exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of Captcha you presented has already been cracked.  An attacker can pre-process the image, making it thinner, then thicker (eliminating all the little dots), center each character vertically, then run it through a common OCR.

Comment: Chris, Andrew, Jarrod, and phatfingers, thank you all so much for sharing your thoughts with me. I may should reconsider my choice of a captcha solution.

Comment: Here's an article that can help you evaluate http://elie.im/publication/text-based-Captcha-strengths-and-weaknesses